# How to POST a pdf-lib modified PDF to PocketBase on the server side of a SvelteKit app?

Tags: javascript, sveltekit, pocketbase

I'm currently working on a SvelteKit app that modifies PDFs using "pdf-lib" on the server or (+page.server.js). I want to be able to modify the PDF with data from a "multipart/form-data" and upload the PDF to PocketBase via the ".create" method of the PocketBase js-SDK. However, I'm not sure how to achieve this, I always get "error 400". In the PocketBase logs under Meta I get this:

```
{
  "errorDetails": "pdfFile: Missing required value.",
  "errorMessage": "Failed to create record."
}
```

Here's my current code for retrieving and modifying the PDF:

```
//I simplified the url for this post
const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/files/collectionID/recordID/name_8UcA7AgYqJ.pdf"

async function modifyPdf(formData, url) {
        // Fetch an existing PDF document
    const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());

    // Load a PDFDocument from the existing PDF bytes
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);
        
         // Embed the Helvetica font
    const helveticaFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica);

    // Get the first page of the document
    const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
    const firstPage = pages[0];

    // Get the width and height of the first page
    const { width, height } = firstPage.getSize();

    // Draw a string of text diagonally across the first page
        // these modifications are for testing purposes.
        // In the future i will use data of the formData
    firstPage.drawText('This text was added with JavaScript!', {
        x: 5,
        y: height / 2 + 300,
        size: 50,
        font: helveticaFont,
        color: rgb(0.95, 0.1, 0.1),
        rotate: degrees(-45)
    });
        
        // create new Uint8Array and create new blob object to append to the formData
    const updatedPdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
    const pdfBlob = await new Blob([updatedPdfBytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });

    return pdfBlob;
}
```

Here is the code i use to request the formData, append the modifiedPDF and create a new record in PocketBase:

```
export const actions = {
    open: async ({ request, locals }) => {
                //request formData
        const formData = await request.formData();   

                // modify the base PDF with data from formData
        const pdfBlob = await modifyPdf(formData, locals, url);
                //append the pdf to the formData
                formData.append('file', pdfBlob, 'file.pdf');
                
                //create new record with formData
        try {
            await locals.pb.collection('counterReceipt').create(formData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
            throw error(err.status, err.message);
        }
    }
};
```

the error response I get on the server console:

```
Error:  ClientResponseError 400: Failed to create record.

...

url: 'http://...',
  status: 400,
  response: {
    code: 400,
    message: 'Failed to create record.',
    data: { file: [Object] }
  },
  isAbort: false,
  originalError: null
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!